# Jquery remove element after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i was just wondering. Why does this work:

```
$("input[name='edit-meta']").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode=='32'||e.keyCode=='13'){
        var clicked=$(this);
        var tag=$(this).val();
        clicked.siblings("#edit-meta").append('<span style="background:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[9]?>;color:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[8]?>" class="tag">'+tag.slice(0,-1)+'<a href="#" class="remove" style="background:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[10]?>;color:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[8]?>;margin:5px">x</a></span>');
        clicked.val("");
    }
    $("a.remove").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var clicked=$(this);
        clicked.closest("span.tag").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

And not this:

```
$("input[name='edit-meta']").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode=='32'||e.keyCode=='13'){
        var clicked=$(this);
        var tag=$(this).val();
        clicked.siblings("#edit-meta").append('<span style="background:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[9]?>;color:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[8]?>" class="tag">'+tag.slice(0,-1)+'<a href="#" class="remove" style="background:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[10]?>;color:<?php echo $ad_details_arr[8]?>;margin:5px">x</a></span>');
        clicked.val("");
    }
});
$("a.remove").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clicked=$(this);
    clicked.closest("span.tag").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I thought the .on would be sufficient to allow me to perform handlers yet created just like .live does.

Also stated in the jquery .on page.

"
... ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created
"

Comment: What is it supposed to do and what goes wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:-

```
$(document).on("click" , "a.remove" ,function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clicked=$(this);
    clicked.closest("span.tag").fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

The above thing will not work because a.remove is not available in the DOM.

The first example work because you are attaching event to a.remove after it is added to the DOM.